# auth-constraint element in web.xml

Tags: java, security

Let's say I have 3 sercurity-constrant elements defined in web.xml, everyone pointing to same url-pattern. And I have these 3 auth-constraint element separately defined in each of them:

```
<security-constraint>
...
    <auth-constraint>Role1</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
...
    <auth-constraint>Role2</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
...
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

Who can access resource specified in url-pattern? Nobody or Role1 and Role2?

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue here as well if you wanna check : http://www.coderanch.com/t/498339/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-auth

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can access. Although `<auth-constrant>` elements are additive, the presence of one `<auth-constraint/>` or `<auth-constraint></auth-constraint>` (with no body) overrrides all others and blocks access.